# How to extend Dart class so that a dynamic property gets a proper type

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this class to deserialize a paginated response from a server:

```dart
class PaginatedResponse {
  final int current_page;
  final dynamic data;
  final String first_page_url;
  final int from;
  final int last_page;
  final String last_page_url;
  final String next_page_url;
  final String path;
  final int per_page;
  final String prev_page_url;
  final int to;
  final int total;

  PaginatedResponse({
    this.current_page,
    this.data,
    this.first_page_url,
    this.from,
    this.last_page,
    this.last_page_url,
    this.next_page_url,
    this.path,
    this.per_page,
    this.prev_page_url,
    this.to,
    this.total,
  });

  factory PaginatedResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return json == null
        ? null
        : PaginatedResponse(
            current_page: json['current_page'],
            data:  json['data'],
            first_page_url: json['first_page_url'],
            from: json['from'],
            last_page: json['last_page'],
            last_page_url: json['last_page_url'],
            next_page_url: json['next_page_url'],
            path: json['path'],
            per_page: json['per_page'],
            prev_page_url: json['prev_page_url'],
            to: json['to'],
            total: json['total'],
          );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'current_page': current_page,
        'data': data,
        'first_page_url': first_page_url,
        'from': from,
        'last_page': last_page,
        'last_page_url': last_page_url,
        'next_page_url': next_page_url,
        'path': path,
        'per_page': per_page,
        'prev_page_url': prev_page_url,
        'to': to,
        'total': total,
      };
}
```

That same response is used for multiple different methods that expect different Types on the `data` property.

It would be ideal if I don't have to repeat all the other properties just to change the `data` type.

So how would I go about extending this class to allow for subclasses of this to have their proper Type in data?

Thank you!

Comment: Would it make sense to make `data` a generic type instead?

Comment: @julemand101 probably, I just don't quite understand how to make the implementation for it and later use it...

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that, you need to make PaginatedResponse with generic type of data. Like this:

```dart
class PaginatedResponse<DATA> {
  final int current_page;
  final DATA data;
...
```

The most difficult part is serialization/deserialization support of this by JSON frameworks. To me the best support of generics is implemented in [built_value](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value) package. [See here](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/blob/master/example/lib/generics.dart) for complete example